# Maximizing unique matched pairs without repeating entries

Tags: r

I have a dataset of pairs of firms as demonstrated below:

```
    structure(list(year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001), gvkey_treat = c(212340, 7435, 6008, 6008, 6008, 
6008, 5169, 5169, 5169, 5169, 9850, 14477, 12142, 12142, 12142, 
14590, 14590, 14590, 7912, 7912), gvkey.control = c(3170, 3170, 
1632, 24800, 10115, 12389, 1632, 24800, 10115, 12389, 2146, 2146, 
114524, 5074, 1891, 6403, 11228, 1661, 6403, 11228), pscoredif = c(0.00834195600000004, 
0.007494632, 0.00505072699999998, 0.00736360899999999, 0.00615869899999999, 
0.00785061100000001, 0.015638134, 0.013325252, 0.014530162, 0.01283825, 
0.00707618099999996, 0.000622760999999972, 2.63809999999642e-05, 
0.016737042, 0.00582589899999997, 0.004946012, 0.00147647300000003, 
0.002811854, 0.00478919899999997, 0.00131966)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have a list of firms who are paired in a given year. I need to reduce this list in such a way that a firm only appears once in treat and once in control each year while also retaining the greatest possible number of firms. Secondarily, I would like to keep the matched pairs with the smallest pscoredif value if multiple options are available.

```
year gvkey_treat gvkey.control pscoredif
2000    7435    3170    0.007494632
2000    6008    1632    0.005050727
2000    5169    24800   0.013325252
2000    9850    2146    0.007076181
2000    12142   114524  0.000026381
2001    14590   11228   0.001476473
2001    7912    6403    0.004789199
```

If someone could help explain how to do this in R it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is probably beyond the scope of a stack overflow answer to fully cover, but I think what you're doing is similar to "propensity score matching" (a term used in medical research), and there are a few R packages that do propensity matching.

Comment: Hi Marius. That is exactly what I am doing. Unfortunately, the R packages I have found only match on 1 exact criteria and I have to match on 2 (year and sic code - not shown here).

Comment: @HollyL it seems like you might not need to *match* on year, you could just split the data into years and do a separate matching process for each. That might make it easier to use the existing packages.

Comment: Is that supposed to be the correct answer for this data? if so can you explain how to achieve it step by step? (It's hard to figure out what is meant by "a firm" and what role "pairing" is supposed to play.) If not then make an example with the correct answer. And you really should have more than one year so there can be testing of that grouping aspect.

Comment: @42- I think I have the code listed now to reproduce in R. Sorry for the confusion there. I am trying to create as many 1:1 matched pairs as possible given the possible pairs identified based upon the propensity score (pscoredif). gvkey_treat are firms that received the treatment effect in a given year and gvkey.control are firms that did not. I want to ensure that gvkey_treat and gvkey.control only appear once in a given year pair.

Comment: @Marius Yes, that's probably a good idea.  I will try that if I can't figure out another way to do this in R.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you know how to get data into R objects and the dataframe (or a matrix that you coerced to a dataframe) is named `dat`. Then try this:

```
  small.dat <- do.call(rbind, 
                       lapply( split(dat, dat[1:3]) , 
                              function(d) d[which.min(d$pscoredif), ,drop=FALSE]
                       )      )
```

Untested in the absence of a MCVE, but the intent of the `lapply(split(...,...))` inner section is to split the large data object into many smaller objects within a list structure, and then within each to pick the one line that satisfies you selection criterion. Finally, the `rbind` process will remake the smaller object with only one item from each unique combination of `year`, `gvkey_treat` and `gvkey.control`.

I'm sure you could do something similar to the `lapply(split(...))` with tidyverse's `group_by` and `filter` operations. perhaps even this :

```
library(tidyverse)
 small.dat <- do.call(rbind,
                      dat %>% group_by(dat[1:3]) %>%
                              filter(which.min(.$pscoredif)
                      )
```

There's probably a tidyverse equivalent of `do.call(rbind, ...)` but I'm not well-(tidy)versed at such, as it were.